# Iterate lists/content in block template twig Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-theming, drupal-8

How would I be able to supersede the hierarchical dependencies in Drupal 8's twig engine to be able to loop within the i.e Lists/Views which is assigned to a block. So we would have a template: block--views-block--[machine-name]-1.html.twig You will be required to have the variable {{ content }}

Which then recursively buries itself down to field templates. Its completely killing me that one would need so many levels to produce on block of content.

I would like to iterate within the top custom block template the list.

Attempted

```
{% for key, value in _context  %}
    <li>{{ key }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

To evaluate what is available to iterate down into the object but with no luck. I did though find a nice overriding object structure to reach the field attributes but that was within the field level

```
item.content['#item'].entity.uri.value
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i use this to "generate" a picture from my

> node--news--full.html.twig

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    {{ content.field_newsbild }}
</div>
```

the twig debug suggests some filenames. i took this:

> field--node--field-newsbild--news.html.twig

and in there i wrote:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <img alt="" src="{{ file_url(item.content['#item'].entity.uri.value) }}" class="img-responsive" {{ attributes }} >
{% endfor %}
```

hope i'll help a bit.